# Change the text size of input text form with image

Tags: jquery

I have a form where an image is displayed and the image contains numbers. I would like that the size of the characters in the text form to be the same as the ones in the image. The numbers in the image have the same height and same spacing so if I have the height and width of the image, I get I can set the input form size and spacing of the characters.

I guess with jquery this is feasible???

Thanks,

John.

Comment: you may like to look at http://angstrey.com/index.php/projects/jquery-text-resizer-plugin/ and, just in case you want to set the size using the load event, take a look at the notes: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the size of your image like this:

```
var width = $("#imageId").width();
var height = $("#imageId").height();
```

Then apply styling to your form based on those values:

```
$("form").css("font-size", height+"px");
```

That will match font height to the height of the image.  You'll have to adjust based on the actual relationship between the size of the image and the size of the text within it.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6X3gL/